# How to assign a value of previous row to the current?

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe with such columns: name,surname, message, time
This dataframe is sorted by every columns. I have rows where message = '!' and surname is null. So I want to assign to that row surname of the previous row. Is it possible to do? I tried this

```
mask = df.surname.isna() and df[['message']] = '!' 
df.loc[mask,'surname'] = df[[surname]].shift(-1)
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

First remove double `[]` for `message` for compare by `!` and then use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for both sides per groups by `name`:

```
print (df)
  name surname message
0   aa      ss      dd
1   aa     NaN       !
2  aa1      uu      dd
3  aa1     NaN      ii
4  aa2      rr      tt
5  aa2     NaN       !
6  aa2     NaN       !

mask = df.surname.isna() & (df['message'] == '!')
df['surname'] = np.where(mask, df.groupby('name')['surname'].ffill(), df['surname'])
print (df)
  name surname message
0   aa      ss      dd
1   aa      ss       !
2  aa1      uu      dd
3  aa1     NaN      ii
4  aa2      rr      tt
5  aa2      rr       !
6  aa2      rr       !
```

If use `shift` without `-1` working well only for one rows with Trues in mask if exist before and after non matched mask, in sample data `row=1`:

```
df['surname'] = np.where(mask, df['surname'].shift(), df['surname'])
print (df)
  name surname message
0   aa      ss      dd
1   aa      ss       !
2  aa1      uu      dd
3  aa1     NaN      ii
4  aa2     NaN      tt
5  aa2     NaN       !
6  aa2     NaN       !
```